# Expose secure read URL for file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-filestore

Is there an option for Filestore, same as [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) for GCS?

I would like to open URL to specific document (from the Filestore) in runtime?

Comment: It seems that there is not a possible option in order to use signed URLS in Filestore. I recommend you create a [Feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)  in order that the Google's team be aware of this :)

Comment: This means that apps on top of Filestore have to handle URL access to the files?

Comment: Yes,  I verified the official documentation and post and I did not find information about used signed urls in Filestore :(